# subdomain htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have here a subdomain which i wish to pass on.

```
here the example of url : http://subdomain.domain.com/login
and it should point to : http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/login
```

i write a simple htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|javascript)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

but i always get 500 server error. any body have idea where i wrong?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal, you go to http://subdomain.domain.com/login, get redirected to http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/login, then to http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/index.php/login and so on because you RewriteRule always match.

You can write `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: hi radius, i thanks for help, the error 500 is disappear
but i now get 404 page. 
i already try it in my local, and working great. but in server it come to 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Apache rewrite module is active and your .htaccess file has the following line before any rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: i'm sorry, forget to say that i already have rewrite engine on. i will edit

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `mod_rewrite` enabled, your `RewriteRule` causes an infinite redirection loop, which exceeds the maximum number of redirects and causes an internal server error.

You need to condition your rule so it only rewrites once. For example, this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```